# Catch 2 Keys in same for a diagonal jump

Tags: c, sdl

For the good of my platform game, i need to make a jump on the left or on the right.

I'm doing well with jump on the same place

The only problem that i have is, how to catch both keys in the same time ?

Any tips ? or exemple ?

Comment: You probably want to stop using keyboard events and check the pressed keys (SDL_GetKeyState) each frame instead.

Comment: @immibis but i can't use both in the same time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using @immibis suggestion you can check if any number of keys are pressed at any point in time. In your case you could do it in the following way (basic example code taken from [here](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlgetkeystate.html) and key constants from [here](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlkey.html)):

```
// Get the state array
Uint8 *keystate = SDL_GetKeyState(NULL); 

// Update the state array before checking the keys as per the note in the docs.
SDL_PumpEvents();

if (keystate[SDLK_UP] && keystate[SDLK_LEFT])
   printf("Jumping going left.\n");
else if (keystate[SDLK_UP] && keystate[SDLK_RIGHT])
   printf("Jumping going right.\n");
else if (keystate[SDLK_UP])
   printf("Just jumping.\n");
```

---

**EDIT**

According to the following note in the docs:

> **Note**: Use [`SDL_PumpEvents`](http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlpumpevents.html) to update the state array.

Comment: works but, evey time in my loop the condition is true ... even if i don't press anymore

Comment: the condition is true, he goes from one side to the other. but not sprite by sprite if you know what i mean

Comment: @Gabson I edited the answer adding a call to SDL_PumpEvents which supposedly updates the state array.